# Conditional expectation and independence: converse of classic lemma

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

It is known that if a real random variable $X$ is independent of some sigma algebra $\mathcal{A}$, then almost surely: $$E(X|\mathcal{A})=E(X).$$

I was wondering if there is any kind of converse for this statement (with maybe other assumptions). More precisely, I am looking for a statement of the form : "if $X$ has *some property* and $E(X|\mathcal{A})=E(X)$, then $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: A meaningful version of such a result is difficult to envision since the condition holds for $X=YZ$ with $Y$ $\mathcal A$-measurable and integrable, $Z$ is independent of $\mathcal A$, and $E(Z)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this (?):

$X$ is independent from $\mathcal A$ if and only, if $\mathbb E(f(X)|\mathcal A) = \mathbb E(f(X))$ for all measurable and non-negative $f$.

"$\Rightarrow$": Since $X$ is independent from $\mathcal A$, so is $f(X)$.

"$\Leftarrow$": Let $f$ be measurable and positive and $A\in \mathcal A$. Then

$$\mathbb E(f(X)1_A) = \mathbb E( \mathbb E(f(X)1_A|\mathcal A)) = \mathbb E(1_A \mathbb E(f(X)) = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb E(f(X))$$
Hence $X$ is independent from $\mathcal A$.

---

Depending on your definition / knowledge of independence you may need to employ a monotone class argument to conclude the independence in the last sentence.

Comment: Ok thank you. It is not what I had in mind (it is a general statement) but it is fine to me.

Comment: Well, if you can come up with a more precise idea maybe you could add that to your question or ask a new one. Hope it's still helpful though.